# search not initiated on clicking JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have made a program where one enters a query in the searchbox and then clicks a button to search. However he can also initiate search by pressing enter. 
The code for the button is

```
  b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        search_handler();
        }
});
```

Now the search is succesfully initiated on hitting enter but clicking the button dosen't work. I have placed

```
System.out.println("method called");
```

inside the search_handler() method to verify whether clicking the button actually calls it and every time I click the button it gets printed but I don't see any results popping out.
I can't understand why the same method behaves differently when called from two different places.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that means, that `search_handler();` method is broken :) you have to find that bug on your own (or at least, ask more specific question).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour] as I see you haven't, go through the [help] and learn [ask], post a valid [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, with hardcoded data, no external links to code, no images / format inside the program if not needed, etc. as this will lead to less confusion and more and better answers

Answer (score 2):

Your code shows you adding a custom listener to the button, therefore you must also have some other custom code for the text field. If this code is different you can have different results.

Instead, the same ActionListener should be added to the button and the text field. This way if the user uses Enter while focus is on the text field or uses the mouse to click the button, the same code will be executed.

So your code should look something like:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // do something
    }
});

button.addActionListener( al );
textField.addActionListener( al );
```